# GeoJSON points not referencing to OSM map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geojson, georeferencing

I've got a GeoJSON file that's written like so (it's 70 points, but for brevity I'm showing 5 here)

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "000000" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ 33.934204063569091, -84.540445928999986 ], [ 33.936482815000019, -84.537699346969575 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "000001" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ 33.934204063569091, -84.537699346969575 ], [ 33.936482815000019, -84.534952764939163 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "000002" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ 33.934204063569091, -84.534952764939163 ], [ 33.936482815000019, -84.532206182908752 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "000003" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ 33.934204063569091, -84.532206182908752 ], [ 33.936482815000019, -84.52945960087834 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "000004" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ 33.934204063569091, -84.52945960087834 ], [ 33.936482815000019, -84.526713018847957 ] ] } }
]
}
```

I would like to compare these points vs the OSM map in QGIS, however when importing into QGIS and setting the OSM and this GeoJSON layer, the GeoJSON layer remains unreferenced to the OSM layer

This is the general view of the GeoJSON output:
[image]

But when including the OSM Layer, I'm in Antarctica:

[image]

I've tried setting both the GeoJSON data and the OSM to either 4326 or 3857, but the result is generally the same, either I'm in Antarctica or near Africa at a 0,0 point. I'm noticing though that the coordinates listed in the taskbar seem to be correct for the points, but not correct for the OSM.

Is there a way to Georeference the JSON data to the OSM layer or should I try something else here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess, you've got your latitude and longitude mixed up. You haven't said where you expect the points to be, or how you generated them in the first place, but [34,-84.5] is somewhere around Antarctica - exactly as you are getting.

GeoJSON positions have the first co-ordinate as the easting (or longitude) and the second as the northing (or latitude). See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#page-7

[-84.5,34] is around Atlanta, USA - which may be where you are expecting the points to lie?

So taking your first MultiPoint (000000) - this file will put it in Atlanta.

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "000000" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ -84.540445928999986,33.934204063569091 ], [ -84.537699346969575,33.936482815000019 ] ] } }
]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to:

- set your layer crs to 4326
- the crs of the osm-Layer to 3857
- the project crs to 3857